# How to replace old ROS Turtle version with ROS Fuerte installation

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, 64bit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the "old" ROS Turtle version installed on 64 bit Ubuntu 10.04 from long ago.
Do I need to remove the ROS Turtle version before installing ROS Fuerte?
If so, where may I find instructions to cleanly remove all ROS Turtle so I can install ROS Fuerte in a clean environment.

I'm fairly new to ROS. When you write "just source the setup.sh of the new installation". what do you mean by that?! Could you just give me exact steps to execute? Please verify that your answer implies I'm able to switch back and forth between ROS Turtle, ROS Electric and ROS Fuerte without any version interfering with the other? (so in that case, uninstalling Turtle is not necessary)

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33753/how-to-replace-old-ros-turtle-version-with-ros-fuerte-installation/) by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2012-05-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, just source the setup.sh of the new installation.

If you want to remove an unused install, it depends how you installed it. For a source install, just delete that. If you installed via packages, just use your package manager to uninstall.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) on 2012-05-18**:\